# How do you change variable name and all occurrences of the variable in your code at the same time with a shortcut?

Tags: python, variables, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering if there was a keyboard shortcut to change a variable's name in your code but in a way that I can do it for all of the occurrences of the variable in your code at the same time.

Double-clicking a variable always highlighted the other occurrences so I wondered if it was already suggesting it to me?

[image]

I tried searching up shortcuts with no helpful results.

Comment: Look at your IDE documentation

Comment: @Brinfer I'm a student who just started out, I have no clue what IDE documentation is?

Comment: What program are you using to write your code? An IDE is an Integrated Development Environment. e.g. PyCharm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment

Comment: @bigkeefer Python, but it is a site/platform of my school where we make the exercises, dodona

Comment: You would need to check with them as to what capabilities that platform has. In an IDE it would be known as "refactoring". e.g. In Pycharm you can put the cursor on the variable name and press SHIFT+F6 (Refactor -> Rename), type a new name and PyCharm would change all relevant occurrences for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you're using VS-Code**

Highlight the variable name and press `CTRL+Shift+L`. Then change your variable's name to whatever you want.

**If you're using Sublime Text**

`Alt+F3` on Windows and Linux, or `CTRL+Cmd+G` on Mac OS.

**If you're using PyCharm**

`CTRL+Shift+Alt+J` on Windows and Linux, `Ctrl+Cmd+G` on Mac OS, or `Shift+F6` as said by bigkreifer

I know, I tried to read the documentation, but it's all in dutch and I can't quite understand what it was written, so I'm trying to guess what IDE (Integreated Developing Enviroment, just a fancier text editor) you are actually using